# Transform Static Array into a generated by foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Im a bit lost with this array here, and i need some "light" if you could.

**My situation is:** change some static data from a array to one generated by an foreach.

The static php code example is the following:

```
$p->data = array(
    array(
        array("A",148), //value_1 for letter A
        array("B",238), //value_1 for letter B
        array("C",151)  //value_1 for letter C
        ),
    array(
        array("A",238), //value_2 for letter A
        array("B",338), //value_2 for letter B
        array("C",285)  //value_2 for letter C
        ),
    array(
        array("A",278), //value_3 for letter A
        array("B",138), //value_3 for letter B
        array("C",205)  //value_3 for letter C
        )
);
```

**My problem is:** when i try to generate the same result with a foreach, i'm doing it wrong.. i already tried nested foreach's and get nothing (or doing it wrong too), but this is the closest I reach from the result i need:

```
foreach($result as $reg){
    $p->data = array(
        array(
            array($reg['letters'],$reg['value_1'])
        ),
        array(
            array($reg['letters'],$reg['value_2'])
        ),
        array(
            array($reg['letters'],$reg['value_3'])
        )
    );
};
```

Instead, i get only the first Letter with the right values. If i use "$p->data[]" to show the other letters, it doesn't work.

The var_dump() i get from the code above is the following:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> array(2) {
             [0]=> string(1) "A"
             [1]=> int(148) }
        }
    [1]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> array(2) {
             [0]=> string(1) "A"
             [1]=> int(238) }
        }
    [2]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> array(2) {
             [0]=> string(1) "A"
             [1]=> int(278) }
        }
}
```

As you see, only the first variable 'letter' comes from the array. I need the others, like this:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(1) "A"
            [1]=> int(148)
        }
        [1]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(1) "B"
            [1]=> int(238)
        }
        [2]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(1) "C"
            [1]=> int(151)
        }
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(1) "A"
            [1]=> int(238)
        }
        [1]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(1) "B"
            [1]=> int(338)
        }
        [2]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(1) "C"
            [1]=> int(285)
        }
    }
    [2]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(1) "A"
            [1]=> int(278)
        }
        [1]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(1) "B"
            [1]=> int(138)
        }
        [2]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(1) "C"
            [1]=> int(205)
        }
    }
}
```

**Explaing the code:** in the foreach im using.. im getting the values from a database. Each variable "Letter" has 3 variable "Values". What im trying to do is show one same variable Value for each Letter separated on each array.

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thank you all o/

Answer (score 0):

what is $reg['letters']? where does $result come from?

you will need an array of letters, and you will need to iterate that. with a little more info i could provide an example.

Comment: $reg['letters'] --- 'letters' is a column in my database. I use the foreach to read every sentence from a sql result. 'letter's is a part of this result.

Comment: so does$result[0]['letters'] = 'ABC';? If you have 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', can you not have 'letter_1', 'letter_2', 'letter_3'?

Comment: i'm sorry, i mean as it goes on , $result[1], [2]. [3] etc. if it's returning A for every one it means it's getting the same result for every one. that's where the error lies.

Comment: im trying to get the values [1,2 and 3] for eacn letter. But im getting only the values [1,2 and 3] for the firts letter. Each Letter has 3 different values from 3 different variables.